# C# Inline expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, inline

I am using the following piece of code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdMapsDrive" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="90%" AllowSorting="true" GridLines="Horizontal" 
                RowStyle-Height="20px" BorderWidth="0"  DataKeyNames = "ID" EmptyDataText="No Maps Found."
                    Style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" OnRowDataBound="grdMapsDrive_RowDataBound">
```

I want to set `EmptyDataText="No Maps Found."` if `txtMapView.Text="No Maps"`. Also I want to set `EmptyDataText="No Data."` if `txtMapView.Text="Data"`.
Where `txtMapView` is a textbox.

I tried various ways using inline code expressions but could not succeed
Can anybody help me with the right expression in C#.

Thanks,
Gagan

Comment: Why can't you set this in code?

Comment: I would recommend to avoid using C# on the aspx page and filter all data in the code

Comment: How are you seeting the text for `txtMapView`?